# How to connect to sybase from PHP in UNIX using ODBC+FreeTDS?

Tags: php, linux, odbc, sybase, freetds

I have tried to connect sybase from terminal using FreeTDS and it is working fine but I am not able to connect database using PHP.

I have done changes in below files.

`/etc/odbc.ini` file:

```
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
Server = 
Port = 
Database = 
Username = 
Password =
```

`freetds.conf` file

```
[sybase]
    host=
    port=
    Tds version=5.0
```

It is working fine using Terminal

```
tsql -S SYBASE -U username -P password
```

But from PHP connection I am getting error:

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

PHP file code:

```
$db = ADONewConnection('odbc');

$DSN ='UID=username;PWD=password;EngineName=dbServiceName;AutoStop=No;Integrated=No;Debug=No;DisableMultiRowFetch=No;CommLinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{};Compress=No;Driver={FreeTDS}';

$db->Connect($DSN );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know in some versions, you need to use the IP of the server rather than the name, like this in `freetds.conf`:

```
[myserver]
    host = 10.10.10.10
    port = 5000
    tds version = 5.0
```

I also don't know if `tds version` is case sensitive, but I've always seen it in lowercase. Are you sure that PHP is reading from the same `freetds.conf` that the command line version is?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. I have added IP address and free tds version in connection string.

Comment: Great to hear! Can you mark the answer correct? Cheers.